# using SqlDependency class to populate ICollectionView with EntityFramework in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqldependency, icollectionview

I want to refresh the ICollectionView object which has some product when a new product is added to database.

How can I achieve this in C#, I am using EntityFramework for DAL.

Comment: SqlDependency class will retrieve only the added products? or you will query all products?

Comment: i need only the added products and add them to collection view

Comment: if you get the new products entities just add to the collection, if you have a specific problem with this please add some code to help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I found [following post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server) by "Harry von Borstel" very helpful